# how can I Store the name of file in a variable in different file in through linux

Tags: linux, unix

I have to store file name in a variable in some different file through linux commands, I have tried using storing file name in a variable
Please help me on this

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Do you mean that you have the name of a file in a variable and you want to write that to a file?  `echo $name > output-file`.  Or do you mean that you have a file which contains the name of another file and you want to assign that value to a variable: `name=$( cat other-file )`  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes , i wil be storing the file name in a variable and now I have to store the same file name in different file, is some other way i can achieve this, I hope you understands my question,

Answer (score 1):

Play around with it a bit more, but these lines should help you get what you need:

```
FILENAME="Your/filename.wat" 
echo $FILENAME
touch $FILENAME 
echo $FILENAME >> TheFilesFileName.txt 
cat TheFilesFileName.txt
OLD_FILENAME=$(cat TheFilesFileName.txt)
```

Comment: The main line here being `echo $FILENAME >> TheFilesFileName.txt` which means that your variable `FILENAME` will be appended to the end of `TheFilesFileName.txt`